# Verificar existencia - INSERT IGNORE o Insertar ON DUPLICATE KEY - MYSQL y PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Me ha surgido la siguiente duda en cuanto a nivel de programación.
Tengo la simple tarea de insertar y actualizar datos desde una tabla a otra, desde un servidor a otro.

Como dije, la tarea es simple, pero me salta la siguiente duda:

¿Cuál procedimiento es más seguro y efectivo? - ¿Hay mejoras en usar uno frente a otro?

A mi parecer, tengo 3 opciones

***Select - Insert y Update***

```
$id = "123";
$select = "SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE id = $id";
$resSel = mysqli_query($conexion, $select);
if(mysqli_num_rows($res)>0){
    //El registro ya existe, se actualizan los datos
    $update = "UPDATE tabla SET columna = valor";
    [...]
}else{
    //El registro no existe, se insertan los datos
    $insert = "INSERT INTO tabla (columna) VALUES (valor)";
}
```

***Insert Ignore***

```
$insert = "INSERT IGNORE INTO tabla (columnas) VALUES (valores)";
$res = [...]
[...]
```

***INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY***

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO tabla (columna) VALUES (valor) 
           ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
               columna1 = valor1, 
               columna2 = valor2,
               [...]
          ";
```

***REPLACE*** - Desconozco exactamente el uso de esta, pero dice funcionar igual que INSERT, solo que borra una fila que tenga un PK existente.

```
$replace = "REPLACE INTO tabla VALUES (col1, col2)";
```

Comment: Por preferencia, siempre uso la primera opción. Por cierto, aún hay una cuarta con [REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html), muy similar a la tercera en funcionamiento, aunque desconozco si hay ventajas de rendimiento entre cada una de ellas.

Comment: Gracias por insertarme una duda más a la lista jaja, la agregaré a ver si alguien sabe más del tema.

Comment: En cuanto a seguridad, depende de cómo armes tus consultas, pero creo que lo que realmente te preocupa es integridad y, en mi humilde opinión, es en lo que deberías enfocarte, dejando el rendimiento en segundo término.

Comment: A que te refieres con integridad ?? Que los datos enviados sean exactamente los mismos ?

Comment: Seguridad = Evitar ataques, Integridad = Datos correctos, evitando problemas con claves primarias y foráneas.

Comment: Por ataques no debo preocuparme tanto, el sistema es una red interna. Integridad es mi foco, por eso esto esta en pruebas aún.

Comment: ¡Eso es lo que estaba suponiendo! Que ya tienes cubierta la parte de seguridad y en esta pregunta buscas integridad y rendimiento.